# JQuery add additional data to new Option

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if there is a possibility to add an additional data to a JQuery new Option. 
I got some select object and I append dynamically content:

```
select.append(new Option(item.name, item.id))
```

which produces a HTML for example like:

```
<option value="22">Uniqa OC Zawodu</option>
```

I want to add additional data to option, so my HTML would look like:

```
<option value="22" data-url="some_data">Uniqa OC Zawodu</option>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you have is vanilla JavaScript, you are not using jQuery library. Using jQuery you can pass an object to it. The properties of the object are mapped to their corresponding DOM properties. Note that `data-*` properties are cached by jQuery internally, and they are not added as attributes to the DOM, so they are not visible:

```
$('<option/>', {
    text: 'Uniqa OC Zawodu',
    value: 22,
    data: {
      url: 'some_data',
      whatever: 1 
    }
}).appendTo(select);
```

For retrieving the `data-*` properties you can use `.data()` method:

```
var url = $('option').data('url');
```

Comment: It works, but that is a little bit confusing to me, because this 'data-url' is not visible.

Comment: Is it because of security reason and not having a possibility to change this paremeter via for example Chrome DevTools?

Comment: @Dawid No, as far as I know browsers do not restrict setting/getting `data-*` properties.

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
 $('#SelectOptionId').append('<option value="22" data-url="some_data">someData</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like

```
$('option').attr('data-url','some_data');
```

Answer (score 0):

After the appends, just do something like this :

```
$('select > option').each(function(i, item) {
 var element = $(item);
 element.data('url', 'some_data');
});
```

Example here :
http://jsfiddle.net/2eeSt/